# jQuery - Checking existence of appended div with has()

Tags: jquery, append, detach

I'm trying to detach a div appended to another one. I'm using the has() method to check if the div exists inside the other. In the first condition (if), the code is doing what it needs to be done. But in the second one (else if), where I did the same steps of the first one, is not working at all. I' not sure if I'm not using the has() method correctly or if the problem is in another place, but the condition is not being checked as it should.

Thanks in advance for any further help.

I'm pasting the CSS code as well, just to make it easier to test. Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="colors" class="divs">
        <span>COLORS</span>
    </div>
    <div id="numbers" class="divs">
        <span>NUMBERS</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="return">
    <span id="text_return">Return</span>
</div>

<div id="colors_container" class="divs">
    <span>Colors container</span>
</div>

<div id="blue" class="divs">
    <span>Blue - Description</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main
{
    background-color: #840002;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#colors
{
    background-color: green;
}

#numbers
{
    background-color: red;
}

#return
{
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#colors_container
{
    background-color: purple;
}

#blue
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.divs
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var numbers;
var colorsContainer = $("#colors_container").detach();
var blue = $("#blue").detach();
$("#text_return").html("");

//Click - #colors
$("#colors").on("click", function()
{
    numbers = $("#numbers").detach();
    $("#main").append(colorsContainer);
    $("#text_return").html("Return");
});

//Click - #colors_container
$("#main").on("click", "#colors_container", function()
{
    colorsContainer = $("#colors_container").detach();
    $("#main").append(blue);
});

//Click - #return
$("#return").click(function()
{
    if($("#main").has("#colors_container")) //WORKS FINE
    {
        colorsContainer = $("#colors_container").detach();
        $("#main").append(numbers);
        $("#text_return").html("");
    }
    else if($("#main").has("#blue")) //NOT WORKING - Not detaching "#blue" div
    {
        blue = $("#blue").detach();
        $("#main").append(colorsContainer);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery's `.has()` returns a jQuery object, your if condition will always always be true (since an object is a truthy value in javascript). Therefore call the `.length()` property inside your condition:

```
if($("#main").has("#colors_container").length > 0)
```

Instead of .has(), you can also use use  [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$("#return").click(function()
{
    if($("#main").children("#colors_container").length > 0) 
    {
        colorsContainer = $("#colors_container").detach();
        $("#main").append(numbers);
        $("#text_return").html("");
    }
    else if($("#main").children("#blue").length > 0) 
    {
        blue = $("#blue").detach();
        $("#main").append(colorsContainer);
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, buddy.

Comment: @AndersonGama don't forget to accept the answers that worked for you :)